# Expectation of Min/Max of N i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have $N$ i.i.d. exponential random variables with each variable having an expected value $\lambda$. Then, how can we represent the expected value of the maximum of these variables in terms of the expected value of minimum of these variables?

Up to this point I know that the expected value of minimum of these variables is $E(min)=\lambda/N$ and the expected value of the maximum of these variable is $E(max)=\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{i=N}\frac{1}{i}$ (is it right? because I am not sure about this). So, is it right to write $E(max)=N\times E(min)\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}\frac{1}{i}$?

BR

Frank

Comment: The expected value of the maximum is right.  So it is correct to write what you did.